# Placing Hyperlinks in DataGrid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datagrid, datatable

I am very statically trying to place hyperlinks into datagrid table rows. Because there are multiple datagrids on my page created by a repeater, not every datagrid (or column) requires a hyperlink. Currently I am doing this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tableCopy.Rows)
{
    row[3] = "<a href:'" + row[3] + "/rev/" + row[1] + "'>" + "test" + "</a>";
}
```

On the page the hyperlinks appear, but when I go to press one the windows text cursor appears: [image: cursor appears]

I am new to asp.net and web programming in general. How can I make these actual click-able links? Thank you.

Comment: give me an example what is in row[3] and row[1]

Comment: row[3] = http://someRepository.com, row[1] is a guid

Comment: try prefixing row[3] with h tt p://w w w.

Comment: instead of href: try href= instead

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu I feel sufficiently stupid now. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @stazima No don't feel stupid. Every single person on this website has made this same mistake or something similar. Code can be so tedious sometimes that its the little things we miss. Sometime you just need a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 row[3] = "<a href='" + row[3] + "/rev/" + row[1] + "'>" + "test" + "</a>";
```

I believe the colon after "href" is whats preventing you from clickable links. Change the colon to an "="